# Read a txt file and split into 2 csvs based on regex

Tags: python, regex, lambda

So I have been told that my code is not good and needs refactoring. I'm struggling to see what I need to do. How do I specify the success and failure conditions for lambda? Also don't get what the method `process_lines` should contain. Any help is greatly appreciated!

These are the comments I was given:

> Let's create a function (process _lines) that accepts 2 lambda functions (success, failure). The success will accept the function pointer that will write to good csv file, while failure to the bad csv file.
>
> Something like:
>
> ```
> def process_lines(success, failure):
> ...
> def write_to_csv(csv_file):
> ...
> process_lines(lambda: write_to_csv(good_csv), lambda: write_to_csv(bad_csv))
> ```

Currently this is my code:

```
import re
import csv

pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+) +([0-9\.-]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+)")

good_csv = []
bad_csv = []
fname = "track_param_hist.txt"
good_csv_fname = "good_hist_csv.csv"
bad_csv_fname = "bad_hist_csv.csv"


class ConvertTxtToCsvs:
  def process(self):
    print("Script for splitting text file into two separate csvs...")
    # read in the text file and store the lines as a list
    with open(fname) as f:
      lines = f.readlines()

    # split the lines into good and bad
    for line in lines:
      good_csv.append(line) if pattern.match(line) else bad_csv.append(line)

    # create the csv for bad data
    with open(bad_csv_fname, 'w') as myfile:
      wr = csv.writer(myfile)
      for line in bad_csv:
        row = (' '.join(line.split())).split(' ')
        wr.writerow(row)
    print("Csv for the bad data has been created successfully")

    # create the csv for good data
    with open(good_csv_fname, 'w') as myfile:
      wr = csv.writer(myfile)
      for line in good_csv:
        row = (' '.join(line.split())).split(' ')
        wr.writerow(row)
    print("Csv for the good data has been created successfully")

# This can also be run as regular python script
if __name__ == "__main__":
  ConvertTxtToCsvs().process()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It looks like you've made some mistakes transferring your code as some lines wont run in this state. Can you [edit](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/109228/edit) your post to fix the format so it matches how it looks in your original script?

Comment: Also as we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan thanks, refactored and added in what the code does at the top!

Comment: Great, I was able to add an answer and I edited your question a bit to make the title more concise about what the code does. Just to clarify, are the comments feedback you got from someone else? I formatted them as a quote because that's what I think they are, but if I'm mistaken please correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't know why someone's recommending `lambda`s to you like that but it's not at all what I'd do. I do agree there's some refactoring that could be done here though.

## Refactoring

Why is `ConvertTxtToCsvs` a class? It contains only one function, `process`, and no attributes. There's no need for it to be a class. Instead, have it function based, and you should split it up a bit. Notice how writing to the good and bad csvs are mirrors of each other? You should have one `write_csv` function. Since all the code is the same *except* the filename and the data, it's very easy to turn into a function:

```
def write_csv(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile)
        for line in data:
            row = (' '.join(line.split())).split(' ')
            wr.writerow(row)
```

And then it can be called for both like this:

```
write_csv(good_csv_fname, good_data)
print("Csv for the bad data has been created successfully")
write_csv(bad_csv_fname, bad_data)
print("Csv for the good data has been created successfully")
```

Which is much neater. Also notice I changed from using a 2 space indent to 4 spaces. That's suggested by the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and is much more readable. This is especially important since whitespace affects program flow in Python.

Also, you read all the lines of the file up front just to iterate over them anyway. It'd be easier and less resource hogging to just read it line by line. Python makes it very easy, as you can directly iterate over a file-like object.

```
with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f:
        good_csv.append(line) if pattern.match(line) else bad_csv.append(line)
```

And lastly, you create your two lists before the function is called. This is bad, because you couldn't call the function more than once without accidentally including all the old data. Instead create the two lists inside the function so with each function call you create new empty lists.

## Style Notes

I linked the style guide just above and it's a good read, but there's some other stuff I'd like to specifically point out. Some of your namìng isn't helpful. `good` and `bad` are often poor descriptions. Why are they good? Does good mean valid data, matching data, useful data? Instead, consider a name more relevant to what that means. `matched` and `unmatched` perhaps? Similarly, I'd avoid the use of `csv`. A csv is a filetype, your lists are not csvs (yet), so you don't need to include that name.

And don't shorten `filename` to `fname`. That shortened three characters isn't worth the reduced clarity here. And instead of just `filename` it'd be better to use `source` or `source_filename`.

```
source_filename = "track_param_hist.txt"
matched_data_file = "good_hist_csv.csv"
unmatched_data_file = "bad_hist_csv.csv"
pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+) +([0-9\.-]+)" + "+([0-9\.\-+Ee]+)" * 21)
matched = []
unmatched = []
```

You have a lot of comments that you don't really need. Comments should explain complex code or intent that's confusing to follow. There's no need comment about using `with open` and `readlines`. These are simple to follow functions, Python is highly readable that way. This could be a good line to comment:

```
            row = (' '.join(line.split())).split(' ')
```

It took me a moment to realise that it's splitting and rejoining the sentence to ensure that there's only a one space gap instead of any multiple spaces. You should write a comment to clarify this as it's a slightly confusing solution.

Using a ternary in your `for` loop works fine, but is a little hard to read. Ternaries are really best used when they can remove duplicate code and shorten things. Your case is less lines, but just as many words. This might be a better use of a ternary:

```
good_csv.append(line if pattern.match(line) else "")
```

I'd personally think it's better to write the loop this way:

```
for line in lines:
    if pattern.match(line):
        matched.append(line) 
    else:
        unmatched.append(line)
```

This is how I'd rewrite your whole script in the end:

```
import re
import csv


source_filename = "track_param_hist.txt"
matched_data_file = "good_hist_csv.csv"
unmatched_data_file = "bad_hist_csv.csv"
pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+) +([0-9\.-]+)" + "+([0-9\.\-+Ee]+)" * 21)


def write_csv(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile)
        for line in data:
            # Make sure all whitespace is reduced to one space character
            row = (' '.join(line.split())).split(' ')
            wr.writerow(row)            


def process(source):
    print("Script for splitting text file into two separate csvs...")

    matched = []
    unmatched = []

    with open(source) as f:
        for line in f:
            if pattern.match(line):
                matched.append(line)
            else:
                unmatched.append(line)

    write_csv(matched_data_file, matched)
    print("Csv for the good data has been created successfully")
    write_csv(unmatched_data_file, unmatched)
    print("Csv for the bad data has been created successfully")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process(source_filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Building up on [@SuperBiasedMan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/109234/84718) good answer, you can improve your memory management using [generator-iterator methods](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods); especially if you use large files:

```
import re
import csv

source_filename = "track_param_hist.txt"
matched_data_file = "good_hist_csv.csv"
unmatched_data_file = "bad_hist_csv.csv"
pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+) +([0-9\.-]+)" + "+([0-9\.\-+Ee]+)" * 21)

def write_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile)
        try:
            while True:
                line = yield
                # Make sure all whitespace is reduced to one space character
                row = (' '.join(line.split())).split(' ')
                wr.writerow(row)
        except GeneratorExit:
            print("Csv", filename, "has been created successfully")         

def process(source):
    print("Script for splitting text file into two separate csvs...")

    matched = write_csv(matched_data_file)
    next(matched) # execute up to the first yield
    unmatched = write_csv(unmatched_data_file)
    next(unmatched)

    with open(source) as f:
        for line in f:
            if pattern.match(line):
                matched.send(line)
            else:
                unmatched.send(line)

    matched.close()
    unmatched.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process(source_filename)
```